# Add a progress bar when deciphering files gpg

Tags: shell, gnupg

For the ease of use for ciphering and deciphering files and folder, and also to get some clues about when it's going to finish, I would like to set up some king of progress bar with gpg.
I'm using `pv` to do so, which works well for ciphering as I do not need a password.
However, I don't know how to do it for deciphering, as it may ask for the password of my private key.
Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || ! [ -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 CIPHERED_FOLDER" >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo "Deciphering $1"
pv $1 | gpg -d | tar -xz
```

It works well if the passphrase is already cached, but fails if it's not.
So I used a workaround, replacing the last line with `gpg -d $1 | pv -W | tar -xz`
However, as I can't know the exact size of the deciphered file, I can't have a percentage.

Is there a way to get this working? I tried looking at ways to manually ask in the script for the passphrase before trying to decipher to get it in the cache, but I couldn't find how to do so.

Thanks

Edit: I'm ciphering the files only for myself for security storage, and gpg doesn't ask me for a recipient anymore because I've set up `default-recipient-self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better solution than my previous answer.

```
gpg -d <(pv $1) | tar -xz
```

The `<()` operator makes gpg read from a file descriptor created for `pv` while still allowing the passphrase to be read from stdin.
Here is where I took the solution from: https://serverfault.com/questions/40284/create-virtual-file-from-bash-command-output

---

Old answer for reference:

I managed to find a workaround.
I first sign a short text and throw the output directly in /dev/null.
This way, it makes sure that the passphrase is cached before the main deciphering.
It looks like this:

```
gpg -o /dev/null --sign <(echo "1234")

echo "Deciphering $1"
pv $1 | gpg -d -q | tar -xz
```